# Return a reference in PHP

Tags: php, reference, php-5.3

I am having difficulty understanding PHP's memory model.

Specifically, what how should I change `$fn` so that `$b` references `$a`, and `var_dump` prints a non-empty array?

```
$a = array();
$fn = function() use (&$a) {
    return $a;
};
$b = $fn();
$b['a'] = 1;
var_dump($a);
```

(More generally, do you have a recommended reference for me on when/how to use references?)

EDIT: Examples in other languages, in which `a` becomes non-empty.

Python:

```
a = {}
def fn():
    return a;
b = fn()
b['a'] = 1
print a
```

Javascript

```
var a = {};
var fn = function() {
   return a;
};
b = fn();
b['a'] = 1;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: It's still not an explanation of your original task

Comment: Yes, and that is deliberate. The "real task" is a couple hundred lines of code, or tens of thousands of lines if you care about what it references. Describing the problem in words would introduce gobs of irrelevant details. I made an abstraction of my problem on purpose.

Comment: well, what you've shown is a smell. And knowing the real task could help us to provide you a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
$a = array();
$fn = function &() use (&$a) {
    return $a;
};
$b = &$fn();
$b['a'] = 1;
var_dump($a);
```

The `&()` in the second line indicates that `$fn` should return a reference, and the `= &$fn()` in line 5 says that $b should be assigned by reference.

Result:

```
array(1) { ["a"]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: I had previously tried adding references `&()` and `&$fn`, but I had not tried both at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Btw, make sure you read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php =)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to make the parameter an object since objects are always passed by reference. An instance of [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) would work in this simple case. I must say though you are either dealing with a use case I've never encountered or there is a  fundamental flaw in the design of the structure of your application is this is needed.

```
<?php
$a = new ArrayObject(array());
$fn = function() use (&$a) {
    return $a;
};
$b = $fn();
$b["a"] = 1;
var_dump($a);
```